# Let's do some -ing

Tags: grammar

While some approve of the construction *"do some" + -ing verb* (e.g. *Let's **do some wrestling/punching/kicking**.*), some don't and think it sounds funny.

Is it correct?

Comment: What I am saying is if someone said its sounds "funny" (I assume that means strange or incorrect), you should add that information to your question. Otherwise this is just a personal opinion question without any backing or research..

Comment: of your above -ing samples, I would rather see "Let's wrestle" over let's do some wrestling.   Your other two samples with punching and kicking  sound completely wrong because I want to know what it is that we are punching or kicking - I want an object here.  Let's do some ... just sounds very foreign when there are shorter, more direct ways of stating the same thought.

Comment: @JoeKim - _funny_ can mean _amusing_ (it makes you laugh); _funny_ can also mean _out of place_ (it sounds strange); _funny_ can also mean _off_ (it sounds incorrect). When someone asks for clarification, please provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a hard and fast rule that can be applied here. The three examples you give would sound awkward to most English speakers if used alone. However, it's easy to imagine a footballer saying "I'm going to the park to *do some kicking* practice" adding more detail or a modifier can make a make quite a difference.

There are examples though were your structure does stand alone:

"I'm going to the mall to do some shopping."

"This weekend I must do some gardening/decorating."

Both spring to mind.

Comment: Thank you. It's impossible to see the why part. Then how about "do some bowling" and I just heard from tv that "do some jumping"?

Comment: Joe Kim try this paper on teaching delexical verbs - it won't answer all of your questions but it may help with understanding the problem http://is.muni.cz/th/146869/ff_m/Diplomova_prace-AJ.pdf